# node errors with fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I'm trying to make a JavaScript fetch request which I wrote custom and then I took the Postman version which works in Postman but not in vscode.

The errors I am seeing using the console in VSC are:
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: Headers is not defined
and
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'

So, this works in Postman so I know the request works but I'll add the code anyway. I've also tried to add in my package.json file:
"console": "integratedTerminal",
and I am importing import fetch from "node-fetch";

The full code looks like this:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";
// added 
import { Headers}  from "node-fetch";
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

const SAUCE_USERNAME = process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME;
const SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY = process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY;

let euUrl = `https://api.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com/rest/v1/${SAUCE_USERNAME}/jobs`;
let usUrl = `https://api.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/rest/v1/${SAUCE_USERNAME}/jobs`;

// What information do you want to fetch? 
// gets all jobs
// /rest/v1/{username}/jobs <- returns an empty object, you need to specify a time range
// this gets the last week of jobs, you need to use a unix time stamp
// see https://www.unixtimestamp.com/ for more info
let timeRange = '?from=604800';
// gets specific job
// /rest/v1/{username}/jobs/{job_id}

let myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.set("Authorization", "Basic " + Buffer.from(SAUCE_USERNAME + ":" + SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY).toString('base64'));
console.log(myHeaders)

let requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch(euUrl + timeRange, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Not sure what I could be missing and spent a while looking at this and other stack overflows which suggest breakpoints and so on as I also see:
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
Process exited with code 1

I've added breakpoints using the red dots next to the lines of code and just stuck now. Would appreciate any help.
[image: cannot see the value in the returned json]

Another edit:
Added additional breakpoint which gives me a breakdown after the fetch is made, but it doesn't show me any data... any reason why?
[image: returns empty? objects]

Comment: I have no included import { Headers}  from "node-fetch"; which is returning this screenshot, attached in original and updated.

Comment: If I change the .json to .text I see more information, but the same error as mentioned above: 
 No debugger available, can not send 'variables' Process exited with code 1

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding:
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

Please see edited code above for the final answer.